# How to create two independent branches in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

We are using Mercurial to manage a project A, which links to an old version of external system.

A new version of this external system is now available and I now want to create second version B of the same project to work with this.

Although both versions will share much of their code, I do not want changes to one project to affect that for the other project. I want to change the code base of each independently.

How can I deal with this please?

One way would be to put project B in a new repository, but this would lose the history of previous code. Is there a way to retain the history?

Though I would have preferred a single code base, it is too difficult to add conditional statements to separate these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution is to create a repository for A and clone it to a separate repository, B.  This would maintain the history but all changes to B would be separate from A (assuming you don't push them back).

As Lazy Badger said, you could also use named branches.  It's just a matter of personal preference.

Comment: I followed this option, as it seems the safest when the branches will never be merged.

Comment: If you are working alone then this is probably fine, but in a larger team this kind of implicit setup would have pitfalls. ie someone could push to the wrong repo and cause problems. Named branches would be more foolproof.

Comment: Well, the repos would have different names so it's not really implicit.  You could also commit to the wrong named branch as well.

Answer (score 4):

Use named branches in single repository: one project - one branch